# Find constants in solution for integral $\frac{e^{-ax}}{1 + x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a task to solve following integral:
$$
I(a) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ax}}{1+x^2}dx
$$
This integral could be solved through differential equation (it can be shown after taking second derivative over $a$):
$$
I''(a) = \cfrac{1}{a}-I(a)
$$
Here we can derive solution through variation of parameters:
$$\boxed{
I(a) = (-Si(a) + c_1)\cos(a) + (Ci(a) + c_2)\sin(a)}
$$
My problem is to find constants $c_1$ and $c_2$. One of them could be found through $I(0) = \cfrac{\pi}{2} \Rightarrow c_1 = \cfrac{\pi}{2}$ as
$$
I(0) = \int_0^{\infty}\cfrac{dx}{1+x^2} = \tan^{-1}(x)\ \Big|_0^{\infty} = \cfrac{\pi}{2}
$$

Now I need to find second constant $c_2$ but I cannot get any appropriate condition because $I'(0)$ and $I''(0)$ are undefined and other numbers instead of $a=0$ gave me hard integral to solve. How can I find second constant then?

Comment: $I(+\infty)$ should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $a=\frac\pi2$ and evaluate
$$ 
I(\frac\pi2) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac\pi2 x}}{1+x^2}dx=Ci(\frac\pi2)
$$
which leads to $c_2=0$ and
$$ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ax}}{1+x^2}dx = \left(\frac\pi2-Si(a)\right)\cos(a) + Ci(a)\sin(a)$$